# need lastmodifydate date and count of records for fields in bulk

Tags: soql, schema, macros

I have 500 fields for account object and I have below requirements.

1)Lastmodifydate of Field
2)Count of records in which values is available for the fields.

I have created a queries but those are not efficient because i need to run query almost 500 times .Any suggestion like scehma or Macros in salesforce to get those details

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try `FieldSets`

Comment: What do you mean by "Lastmodifydate of Field"? when the field metadata was modified or each record level last modified date?

Comment: Yes.LastModifiedDate of Field

Comment: @dem Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) For count of not null entries for a fields,

```
Select count(Id),Count(Name),Count(Custom_Field__c) from Account
```

1) For lastModfiedDate of a particular field for each record, you would need to track history for that fields. Then you can query

```
Select AccountId,Field,max(CreatedDate) from AccountHistory group by AccountId,Field
```

Comment: Point N0-1 This is fine for few fields,but i have to check for almost 500 fields ,then each time i need to run separate query for each field ,Is there any way so i can get count in one shot